# Laravel 5.6 apply pivot scope in relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to apply a scope form a pivot class in a morphedByMany relationship included in a User class. This is the relationship:

```
public function nodes($nodeClass)
{
    return
        $this->morphedByMany(
            $nodeClass,
            'node',
            'users_permissions',
            'user_id',
            'node_id',
            'id',
            'id'
        )
        ->using('App\Models\UserNode');
}
```

Then, I have a role scope in the pivot class (UserNode). That scope is not our code, it is from HasRoles Traits from spatie/laravel-permission package:

```
public function scopeRole(Builder $query, $roles, $guard = null): Builder
{
    if ($roles instanceof Collection) {
        $roles = $roles->all();
    }

    if (! is_array($roles)) {
        $roles = [$roles];
    }

    $roles = array_map(function ($role) use ($guard) {
        if ($role instanceof Role) {
            return $role;
        }

        $method = is_numeric($role) ? 'findById' : 'findByName';
        $guard = $guard ?: $this->getDefaultGuardName();

        return $this->getRoleClass()->{$method}($role, $guard);
    }, $roles);

    return $query->whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($roles) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($roles) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                $query->orWhere(config('permission.table_names.roles').'.id', $role->id);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When I try to get specific class of nodes inside User class like this it works perfectly:

```
$nodes = $this->nodes($nodeClass)->get();
```

However, I don't know how I can apply properly the scope 'role' to the pivot class of the relation because wherePivot or wherePivotIn does not accept scopes, relations or closures. I have also tried other things with the same result like:

```
$nodes = $this->nodes($nodeClass)->whereHas('pivot', function($q) use ($roles) {
        $q->role($roles);
    })->get();
```

Is there any way to apply the pivot class' scope to this relation?

Thanks in advance